# What RxJS operators require unsubscription?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I know there are operators that will complete automatically, such as forkJoin, but then there are others which, as far as I understand, never complete and must be unsubscribed to prevent any subscription leaks, such as combineLatest.

Is there a good way to tell which must be unsubscribed from and which are safe? Or at least a full list of them? I'm struggling to get this information from the documentation.

I'm still fairly new to RxJS, so let me know if I seem to be misunderstanding something.

---

Just as a note: I know about using `| async` but I'm working on an existing project and using that is not an option at this point. I also am aware of and am using `takeUntil` in place of the `unsubscribe` method, so this is not in reference to that. I just want to know when I need to use `takeUntil` / `unsubscribe` after using one of the RxJS operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forkJoin` actually doesn't automatically complete. It depends on the observables it's modifying to complete. If those observables don't complete, neither does the one returned by `forkJoin()`. Actually, `combineLatest` has similar qualities.

In general, all RxJS-provided operators create observables that close when the original observable(s) do - or at least one of them.

In practical terms, this means it's on the developer using RxJS to understand the behavior of the observables they're passing to an operator. Could the stream potentially be stuck open forever? In that case we will want to modify it to handle this - perhaps it closes after 5 seconds of no activity.

Point being that operators will either respect the completion of the input observable, or they will modify it (likely by completing it early) because that's what they're designed to do. Most common examples of the latter sort include the "takes": `take`, `takeWhile`, `takeUntil`.

Spend enough time with the library - read the docs for each operator, play around with them in code, or ask here if something specific doesn't make sense, and you'll come to be pretty familiar with which are which.